# WI-FI card: how to enable bluetooth only?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 20.10

I have a Asus H370-i with an Intel Wireless-AC 9560 and Ubuntu 20.10. What should I configure to have bluetooth only? so without WIFI.

Comment: The question is unclear. What is the OS version? You don't need to configure anything for Ubuntu to use this device. Is the question "how to disable Wi-Fi" or what?

Comment: Now I have Ubuntu 21.10; yes, what to configure to disable WI-FI signal but not the bluetooth one.

Comment: Turn off Wi-Fi in NM. It doesn't affect BT.